# Limiting Number of Facebook Feed Posts Using Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a facebook feed aggregator that displays the latest posts from all my pages. I only want 10 posts displayed at a time and then a "more button underneath that displays more posts if clicked. Everything is function except that it displays every post from every page that can be scrolled. The page loads so slowly because of the thousands of posts loading. I have achieved this with my twitter posts  but for some reason not with Facebook. I have posted both the facebook and twitter code so you can compare. I need help limiting the number of posts displayed. Thanks

Here is a link to a screenshot of the software. https://gyazo.com/d1c2363d553de2e267c3eddea5857fc3

Facebook

```
    this.morefacebookpagefeeds = function () {
    var obj = vm.currentfacebookpaging();
    var feedinfo = new Object();
    feedinfo.facebookfeeds = new Array();
    feedinfo.PagingList = new Array();
    var item = 0;
    obj.forEach(function (e, index, array) {
        item++;
        var parameters = e.next.split("?")[1];
        var page = ko.utils.arrayFirst(vm.currentfeedModelArray(), function (i) {
            return i.Id == e.PageId;
        });
        FB.api("/" + facebookuserid + "/feed?" + parameters, 'get', { access_token: facebookaccesstoken }, function (response) {
            response.data.forEach(function (feed, index, array) {
                var feedsdata = new Object();
                feedsdata.Description = feed.description;
                feedsdata.Picture = feed.picture;
                feedsdata.Name = feed.name;
                feedsdata.Link = feed.link;
                feedsdata.Message = feed.message;
                feedsdata.PageName = page.ProfileName != undefined ? page.ProfileName : "";
                feedsdata.PostDate = moment(new Date(feed.created_time)).format('ddd MMM DD YYYY hh:MM a');
                feedsdata.ProfileImage = page.ProfileImageUrl;
                feedsdata.PageUrl = page.ProfileUrl != undefined ? page.ProfileUrl : "";
                feedsdata.Id = page.ProfileId != undefined ? page.ProfileId : "";
                feedinfo.facebookfeeds.push(feedsdata);
                if (response.paging != null) {
                    feedsdata.Paging = new Object();
                    feedsdata.Paging.previous = response.paging.previous;
                    feedsdata.Paging.next = response.paging.next;
                    feedsdata.Paging.PageId = pageId;
                }
                feedinfo.PagingList.push(feedsdata.Paging);
            });

            if (item == array.length) {
                feedinfo.facebookfeeds.forEach(function (item) {
                    vm.currentfeedModelArray.push(item);
                });
                feedinfo.PagingList.forEach(function (item) {
                    vm.currentfacebookpaging.push(item);
                })
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Twitter

```
 this.twitterfeeds = function (sinceid) {
    if (sinceid) {
        var sinceidvalue = vm.currenttwitterfeedModelArray()[vm.currenttwitterfeedModelArray().length - 1].Id;
    }
    ajaxExt({
        type: "POST",
        throbberPosition: { my: "center center", at: "center center", of: $(window), offset: "5 0" },
        data: { sinceid: sinceidvalue },
        url: baseUrl + 'Social/TwitterFeed',
        showThrobber: true,
        success: function (data) {
            vm.feedModelArray.removeAll();
            if (sinceidvalue == undefined || sinceidvalue == null) {
                vm.currenttwitterfeedModelArray.removeAll();
            }
            if (data.Object == null || data.Object.length == 0) {
                $('#loadmoretwitter_btn').css('display', 'none');
            }
            data.Object.forEach(function (item) {
                vm.currenttwitterfeedModelArray.push(item);
            });


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a limit param: `FB.api("/" + facebookuserid + "/feed?limit=10)`

Comment: Thanks and Yes. It does limit the amount of posts per account but I manage close to 60 accounts so it loads all 60 accounts. I want it to load 10 accounts then break and display the "more" button.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit parameter:

```
FB.api('/' + pageId + '/feed', {access_token: facebookaccesstoken, limit: 10}, ...
```

About pagination: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Edit: Since you asked for an example for getting a limited amount of Pages, here is something (untested, quick and dirty):

```
var currentIndex = 0;
function getNextItems() {
    for (var i = currentIndex, count = currentIndex + 10; i < count; i++) {
        if (obj[i]) {
            FB.api(...);
        } else {
            return;
        }
        currentIndex++;
    }
}
```

...on "more" click, just call that function again.

Comment: Since they want to paginate, this should be useful as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: Thanks. It does limit the amount of posts per account but I manage close to 60 accounts so it loads all 60 accounts. I want it to load 10 accounts then break and display the "more" button.

Comment: ok, your description was "limiting the number of posts displayed". for limiting the number of accounts, you can just use a simple for loop, storing the current/last index and loop from <last_index> to <last_index + 10>, and break when there is no element left.

Comment: ...when you click "more", just use the same loop again. you have to put the loop into a function, of course.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to give me an example please? I am not that familiar with javascript. Thank you!

Comment: I added a quick and dirty example. You should really learn javascript though, stackoverflow is not a place to get your work done for free. we are happy to help with tips how to solve stuff on your own though ;)

Comment: make sure you understand what happens in the example, it is just an example how the general flow could be and i am quite tired already ;)